# Copy/paste and Ethernet controller not working in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, ethernet, copy-paste

> <sub>**Note:** I might have given to much information, but better to much than too little. I am Dutch, and my installation of Windows Vista 32bit is Dutch, so some program names have been translated literally.</sub>

I recently re-installed Windows Vista 32bit on my HP A6110.NL desktop computer, which I have upgraded to these specs:

- 650W PSU,
- Pentium 4 650 3.4Ghz CPU,
- 5GB DDR2 SDRAM,
- Geforce 9500 GT 1Gb DDR2 GPU,
- Edimax WiFi PCI-card and
- 2x 160GB HDD (Maxtor (IDE) and Hitachi (SATA)).

The other devices and hardware remain stock. Google "HP a6110.nl" for specs.

It took me quite some time upgrading the PC and keeping it stable, adding one part at a time on the previous installation of Windows Vista. I thought with the hardware-upgrade finally complete it would be wise to re-install Windows Vista so the system would incorporate all new hardware completely with each other and be bug free, because some bugs had sneaked into the system.

Most bugs did "fly off" to bug someone else after the re-install, but the following bugs stayed/re-appeared after completing the numerous updates for the Windows system, which I did right after installing the proper drivers for the new hardware, and a virus scanner (Avira). I did not install *anything* else before making sure I had completed all updates for Windows (took me the better part of a day).

The bug which has stayed messes up the internal Ethernet controller in such a way that **it's unable to connect to my network**. In "networkcentre" it's recieved as "unknown public network". But plugging the same cable in a laptop it does recieves the network just fine and connects perfectly to it.

I have tried numerous things to get it to work but it won't. I even suspect something is wrong with the hardware, although I try and stay hopeful. I'm now connected to my network by WiFi only.

A bug which has returned (although I did not test it thoroughly right after the new installation had completed) makes it **frustratingly random for the copy/cut/paste function to work**. Both `Ctrl+C` or `V`, `Ctrl+P`, as well as *right-click copy/cut*, *right-click paste* do not respond every time. I have to try multiple times for it to work.

---

Both these problems are mere "inconveniences" but are annoying doing the simple stuff like tranferring files to my network drive (wifi has lower speeds) or between folders and editing texts or making documents.